# Change font size on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is the code I have

```
var myFont = new Font2();
typeableText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat2;
typeableText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
typeableText.embedFonts = true;
typeableText.x = 540;
typeableText.y = 400;
typeableText.width = 175;
typeableText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
typeableText.wordWrap = true;
typeableText.multiline = true;
typeableText.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
typeableText.text = "Your text here";

var myFormat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat2.size = 22;
myFormat2.font = 'Franklin Gothic Demi';
myFormat2.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
myFormat2.kerning = true;
myFormat2.leading = 1.5;
```

I want a button click to increment the size of the text by 4 each time the button is clicked but can't figure out how to do it so that the size of the text instantly changes.

Comment: Why `myFont` is shown here?. If you have created it then try using it as `myFormat2.font = myFont;`. The answer given by @Fygo should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
   myFormat2.size += 4;
   typeableText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat2;
   typeableText.setTextFormat(myFormat2);
}
```